# Hora en tiempo real JQUERY

Tags: php, jquery

quisiera mostrarle a mis clientes el tiempo transcurrido (horas y minutos) desde que hicieron su pedido; en 2 lenguajes php y jquery.

Por ejemplo al cargar la web tengo esto

```
<?php 
echo $reporte["hora"]; // hora generada por el sistema y extraida de la base de datos, 06:02; formato 24 horas
?>
```

ahora bien, lo que estoy buscando es una funcion (nativa o externa) que me reste a la actual hora (`date("Hi")`)
y me muestre el resultado en caso sean horas, si fueran mas de 24 horas (un dia) ya no me lo muestre;
por ejemplo (pseudo-codigo):

```
$resta = hora_actual_del_sistema - $reporte["hora"];
if($resta < 23){echo hora : minutos restantes ;}
```

supongamos que ya obtenemos el resultado y es 05:30 (5 horas 30 minutos) ahora, que esto se valla actualizando con forme pasen los minutos tipo facebook(jquery)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

de ante mano gracias por su ayuda.

Nota:

- Mostrar la hora en tiempo real con jquery no es tan importante como restarle minutos y mostrarlo con php
- prove con este codigo pero no me funciona correctamente:

..

```
<? function calcular_tiempo_trasnc($hora1,$hora2){
    $separar[1]=explode(':',$hora1);
    $separar[2]=explode(':',$hora2);

$total_minutos_trasncurridos[1] = ($separar[1][0]*60)+$separar[1][1];
$total_minutos_trasncurridos[2] = ($separar[2][0]*60)+$separar[2][1];
$total_minutos_trasncurridos = $total_minutos_trasncurridos[1]-$total_minutos_trasncurridos[2];
if($total_minutos_trasncurridos<=59) return($total_minutos_trasncurridos.' Minutos');
elseif($total_minutos_trasncurridos>59){
$HORA_TRANSCURRIDA = round($total_minutos_trasncurridos/60);
if($HORA_TRANSCURRIDA<=9) $HORA_TRANSCURRIDA='0'.$HORA_TRANSCURRIDA;
$MINUITOS_TRANSCURRIDOS = $total_minutos_trasncurridos%60;
if($MINUITOS_TRANSCURRIDOS<=9) $MINUITOS_TRANSCURRIDOS='0'.$MINUITOS_TRANSCURRIDOS;
return ($HORA_TRANSCURRIDA.':'.$MINUITOS_TRANSCURRIDOS.' Horas');

} }
//llamamos la función e imprimimos
echo calcular_tiempo_trasnc(date('H:i'),'16:12');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Digamos que la fecha y hora en la que hizo el pedido están en la variable `$fechahora` en PHP (ojo, tiene que estar como DateTime, cualquier cosa fijate en https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.datetime.php).

Para pasar ese valor de PHP a JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // ...

  fechaPedido = new Date(  <?php echo $fechahora->getTimestamp()*1000 ?>  );

  // ...
</script>
```

Luego es tan sencillo como ejecutar alguna función cada 1 minuto por ejemplo:

```
setTimeout(actualizarTexto,60000);
```

que calcule cuánto tiempo pasó:

```
function actualizarTexto() {
    var fechaActual = new Date(),
        diferencia = Math.abs(fechaActual - fechaPedido), //en milisegundos
        enMinutos = Math.floor(diferencia/1000/60);
    
    // ... resto del código
}
```

y edite el elemento que quieras de la página.

Comment: Perfecto amigo, dime; y en php como podria obtener las horas y minutos transcurridos entre una hora y otra?

Comment: @IntruzO https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.diff.php (teniendo en claro que PHP se ejecuta una única vez cuando se obtiene la página, y no va a ir actualizando el texto dinámicamente)

Comment: claro amigo eso esta sobre entendido, php es del lado del servidor. pero mira te comento, lo que yo quiero hacer es algo ligero, no quiero desperdiciar recursos con funciones date de php, quiero mas bien algo matematico, e pensado en eliminar los 2 puntos y que quede de 05:30 a 0530 y restarle la hora actual con ese mismo formato 1025 lo cual me daria 1025 - 0530 = 495 esto seria el resultado

Comment: @IntruzO no hay 100 minutos en 1 hora. Esa cuenta está mal, en todo caso multiplicando hora * 60... ¿Pero qué tiene de complicado usar lo que fue diseñado para eso? `floor(abs((new \DateTime)->getTimestamp() - (new \DateTime('01:15'))->getTimestamp()) / 60)`

Answer (score 1):

Existe la librería llamada [*Moment.js*](https://momentjs.com/) esta hace casi todo por ti.

Para este caso creo una función llamada `convetirATiempo` que llamo al finalizar la carga de `body` este tomara la fecha contenida en todos los elemento con clase `.tiempo` y le agregara el tiempo transcurrido usando la función de momentjs llamada `fromNow()`.

```js
function convetirATiempo(){
 moment.locale('es')
 $('.tiempo').each((i,item) => {
   let fecha = $(item).text()
   let tiempo = moment(fecha , "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm").fromNow();
   $(item).text( fecha + ' - ' + tiempo)
 })
}

convetirATiempo()
```

```html
<ul>
<li>Pedido <span class="tiempo">01/08/2020 04:59</span></li>
<li>Pedido <span class="tiempo">25/09/2020 04:59</span></li>
<li>Pedido <span class="tiempo">27/09/2020 04:59</span></li>
</ul>


<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Otra opción es usar [CARBON](https://carbon.nesbot.com/) una librería de PHP y su función `diffForHumans()`.

Comment: claro amigo, e visto varias opciones para lograr esto, pero queria algo sencillo y directo, ya que una libreria me ocuparia espacio con funciones adicionales y "demas" que a la larga no usare